# Getting parameter values using github.com/spf13/cobra

Tags: go, command-line

I am using the [`github.com/spf13/cobra`](https://github.com/spf13/cobra)  package to interpret process' command-line arguments, and I'm having difficulty understanding how parameter values are determined.

I have a working program (below) which uses internal variables that get updated with parameter values:

```
OptPort := 8088

rootCmd := &cobra.Command{
    Use:   "server",
    Short: "Root command short version",
    Long:  "Root command long version",
}

startCmd := &cobra.Command{
    Use:   "start",
    Short: "Start command short version",
    Long:  "Start command long version",
    Run: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
        fmt.Println("args: " + strings.Join(args, " "))
        fmt.Println("port: " + OptPort)
    },
}
startCmd.Flags().IntVarP(&OptPort, "port", "p", OptPort, "Port to listen to")

rootCmd.AddCommand(startCmd)

rootCmd.Execute()
```

The output I get is as follows:

```
args:
port: 8088
```

I realize that I can get the port value by interrogating the port variable, but I would have thought the values would be in the args variable also.  Is the args variable empty because I am doing something wrong?  If the args variable is expected to be empty, what is the purpose of the args variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `args` variable is for extra parameters that are passed into that particular `cobra` verb. For example, if you wanted your `start` verb on the `server` command to (for example) require a particular configuration file, you could simply pass that in like

`server start -p 8080 config.yml`

and `"config.yml"` is placed in `args[0]`.